# Php sessions aren't working

Tags: php, session, mamp

I am new to php, and very new to sessions, so I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I followed the tutorial on tizag, and put this code on my site:

```
<?php

session_start();

echo SID . "<br><br>";

if(isset($_SESSION['views'])) {
    $_SESSION['views'] = $_SESSION['views'] + 1;
} else {
    $_SESSION['views'] = 1;
    echo "views = ". $_SESSION['views']; 
}

?>
```

The SID changes whenever I refresh, and the number does not count up.

Update: Url: http://121.73.150.105/PIA/

FIXED BY: Putting session_start() before my doctype, title etc.

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the very top of your code. then either read apperaed message or google for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are cookies enabled in you're browser ? phpsessid is stored as a cookie , you can set different parameters for it , one that could be usefull in you're case could be [session_get_cookie_params()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-get-cookie-params.php) , and see if everithing is oki with the session cookie params .

If anything is wrong like expiration date you can set the params with [session_set_cookie_params()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)

Comment: Cookies are enabled, and session_get_cookie_params() just outputs "Array"

Comment: use var_dump(session_get_cookie_params()); and it will output all the info you need .

Comment: That outputs "array(5) { ["lifetime"]=> int(0) ["path"]=> string(1) "/" ["domain"]=> string(0) "" ["secure"]=> bool(false) ["httponly"]=> bool(false) } "

Comment: you need to set the lifetime and domain , carefull with the domain if the browser sees and ip it whont accept a domain name .

Comment: So... I can't use sessions on my local testing server?

Comment: you can use sessions , you just need to set domain to the ip you're using.

Comment: But when I upload it to production I have to change it?

Comment: shure you have to change it , you should have a config file in you're app and define the development configs and production configs , then you don't have to change anything when you upload to the production server .

Comment: what tha nonsense you are talking about?? NO NEED to set lifetime and domain

Comment: Col. Shrapnel: That's what I thought. How do I fix it then?

Comment: @JJ56 don't listen to him. DO NOT even touch lifetime. It should be 0 ever. As for the domain, as long your site using no subdomains, it's no need to touch that setting too. These settings you have at this moment are default ones and any site should work perfectly with it

Comment: use @highelf answer and see if it works . i've made a test on my localhost and it works with the session settings you have , however you're site doesn't set the session cookie.

Comment: @poelinca Dosen't it? what do you mean?

Comment: @JJ56 as it can be seen, you server doesn't send a session cookie for some reason. I'd suggest to turn dislaying errors on and see what it says. I suspect there will be someting interesting.

Comment: @JJ56: i mean you're php file response headers don't set the PHPSESSID cookie , so whe you request the php file the browser doesn't send the cookie containing the session id with php should use . since php doesn't recive a phpsessid from you it whont know witch session to use so it will create a new one . session_start() should detect if you're browser has a phpsessid cookie , and if not it will set one for you , but it doesn't so i suppose one of the session.use_cookies is not set as it should . and yes as Col. Shrapnel sayd turn on error reporting ,might be errors witch set different headers

Comment: I am the blind idiot. the reason is as clear as fresh water. It can be seen with unarmed eye by just navigating the link provided in the OP

Comment: Here is the session cookie bit out of php.ini: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/182509/Screenshots/04.png

Comment: @Col. Sharpnel: what kind of completely foolish nonsense is that? **Of course** you must set the lifetime, otherwise the cookie will expire at the end of the session!

Answer (score 0):

You don't output the `$_SESSION['view']` after the if statement. I think that's why it doesn't change.

Try:

```
<?php

session_start();

echo SID . "<br><br>";

if(isset($_SESSION['views'])) {
    $_SESSION['views'] = $_SESSION['views'] + 1;
} else {
    $_SESSION['views'] = 1;
}

echo "views = ". $_SESSION['views'];     

?>
```

So you always output the new `$_SESSION['views']` value.

EDIT:
I think the right answer is that the session is not set. But I'm curious, how can the code always outputs "view = 1"? Can I open a new question referencing this question or just discuss it here?

Comment: because a new session always starts

Comment: Oh I see. Because the <pre>$_SESSION['view']</pre> is never set, then it always become a new session and get in the else statement. Is that right? Thanks before.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP setup may have been configured to not save sessions in cookies.

To verify if this is the case, you can take a look at [session.use_cookies](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-cookies) in your php.ini, or using [ini_get](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php), like so:

```
<?php echo ini_get('session.use-cookies'); ?>
```

You can correct it at runtime, as well, using [ini_set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php), like so:

```
<?php ini_set('session.use-cookies', '1'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

either you are outputting something to the browser before calling session start, or you have cookies disabled.

Answer (score 0):

in your code if you cant see session ID you can write
`session_id()` in place of `SID`.

Answer (score 0):

`ini_set("session.use_cookies",1);

ini_set("session.use_only_cookies",1);`

this two parameter must set to gether if you want it work

Comment: ok i cant add comment to Sebastian P. then i forced to send new answer sorry